# Access the query string from SPFx web part using React

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm rebuilding a SP 2013-era EditForm.aspx web part using SPFx & React.

I would appreciate advice on how to get the query string into a SPFx web part.

I don't see any methods in the SharePoint Framework Reference; I apologize if I missed something.

I'm using React - its documentation leads to React-router, which seems overkill for just getting an item id, not to mention the struggle of changing the components at the root of the SPFx web part.

I've reviewed the PNP-JS-Core, and didn't find any help there either.

How are other people doing this?

Comment: Why not simply use pure JS to get the query string parameters from `window.location.href`? Or even simpler with `window.location.search` which gives you only the query string, but it is not supported below IE11 and some other old browser versions.

Answer (score 8):

spfx has some utility classes to help. start by

```
import {  UrlQueryParameterCollection } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
```

Then in your onRender:

```
 var queryParameters = new UrlQueryParameterCollection(window.location.href);
    if (this.properties.mode !== modes.NEW) {
      if (queryParameters.getValue("Id")) {
        const id: number = parseInt(queryParameters.getValue("Id"));
        let fields = "*,ParentTR/Title,Requestor/Title";
        // get the requested tr
        pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Technical Requests").items.getById(id).expand("ParentTR,Requestor").select(fields).inBatch(batch).get()
          .then((item) => {
```

I create a 'mode' property on the property pane to specify if the form is in new, edit or display mode. Throw an error if no id is specified in display or edit mode. this example uses pnp-js-core.

hth

Comment: 'UrlQueryParameterCollection' is deprecated. Use the URLSearchParams browser API instead.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Mihail!

I copied [Waldek's getLatestItemId method](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/sharepoint-crud/src/webparts/reactCrud/components/ReactCrud.tsx) and added in the window.location.

I'm not going to pretend I know how Promises work, especially in TypeScript, but so far so good.

If the query string doesn't happen to have a number, then it returns a nice message saying to call me.

```
private getListItemId(): Promise<number> {
    let strLocationSearch: string = window.location.search.split("id=")[1];
    let numLocationSearch: number = parseInt(strLocationSearch);
    return new Promise<number>((resolve: (itemId: number) => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
        this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.listName}')/items(${numLocationSearch})?$select=id`,
            SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
                    'odata-version': ''
                }
            })
            .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ Id: number }> => {
                return response.json();
            }, (error: any): void => {
                reject(error);
            })
            .then((response: { Id: number }): void => {
                if (response.Id === numLocationSearch) {
                    resolve(response.Id);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(-1);
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `UrlQueryParameterCollection` is deprecated, I suggest to use the [URLSearchParams](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams) browser API instead.

Here is my code to **get** value of *search* parameter:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let searchParam: string;
params.has('search') ? searchParam = params.get("search") : searchParam = "";
```

Here is my code to **delete** *search* parameter and update URL:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
if (params.has('search')) {
  params.delete('search');
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${location.pathname}?${params}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify more the answer by Raf, you can directly use the url.search like below. Here I am getting value of ID parameter.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
let val = params.get('ID');
console.log(val);
```